# What the difference in Initializing selenium driver?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I user Cucumber + selenium. I create Auth test, it look like this

```
public class AuthTestSteps {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static WebDriverWait wait;

    @Given("^some condition$")
    public void some_condition(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    }
    @If("^open link \\\"(.*)\\\"$")
    public void open_link(String pageUrl){
         driver.get(pageUrl);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(Auth.profileBtn));
         Auth.clickProfileBtn(driver);

}
    .....
```

That test work well, it doing all what i want, but i try to create another test. It simple as much :

```
public class CallDoctorTestStep {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static WebDriverWait wait;


    @Given("^some condition$")
    public void нужно_вызвать_врача(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    }
    @IF("^some condition \\\"(.*)\\\"$")
    public void пользователь_перейдет_на_главную(String pageUrl){
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(pageUrl);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(CallDoctor.callDoctorBtn));
    CallDoctor.clickCallDoctor(driver);
}
   ...........
```

As you can see, difference is minimal, but! When i try to start `CallDocrotTestStep` it faild at `If` Condition with nullPointerException. Browser do not start. So i tryed to search, what the problem. And problem in initializing, if i init `driver` as CallDoctorTestStep class field like this : `private static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` it will start browser. I think problem in visibility of variables, but why the `AuthTestStep` work well, but `CallDoctorTestStep` is not working if i init `driver` like in `AuthTestStep`?

Comment: You should handle webdriver initialization in a different manner. Example: `@Before` tag

Answer (score 0):

You have declared

```
private static WebDriver driver;
private static WebDriverWait wait;
```

in class AuthTestSteps.

The access modifier `private` signified they are only accessible inside the class where they are declared, in this case AuthTestSteps.
That means that the class CallDoctorTestStep cannot access them, like you said.

To share state between your StepDefinitions, have a look at using Dependency Injection(DI). Cucumber supports several DI frameworks, you can read more about them here: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/java-di